# Parsing large XML files and generating SQL tables dynamically

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, xsd, avro

I have a huge complex xml file from which xsd/database-tables are to be generated. Since it is a huge file I look at it in a Hadoop scenario. 
I have checked many ways of processing an XML (in hadoop) like:

1. Converting XML to AVRO format
2. Using Mahout XMLInputFormat
3. Overriding RecordReader class of Map Reduce
4. Loading XML directly to Hive tables using Oracle XMLextension
   but.. we all the above methods need xml tags/elements to be hard coded manually.
   for e.g.  consider foo.xml

```xml
 <CustomerReport>
     <Customer>
      <CustomerName>DKIJzuUG</CustomerName>
      <CustomerStatus>active</CustomerStatus>
      <age>70</age>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <AquistionChannel>uBeApXji</AquistionChannel>
      <State>MZlNWI</State>
      <HouseholdIncome>0506</HouseholdIncome>
      <Revenue>54961</Revenue>
      <PurchaceOrders>
       <PurchaceOrder>
        <PurchaceOrderName>qkiHEH</PurchaceOrderName>
        <purchasedOn>02-01-2014</purchasedOn>
        <amount>899</amount>
       </PurchaceOrder>
      </PurchaceOrders>
             ......
     </Customer>
    </CustomerReport>
```

In all the above methods I listed above - hard coding of the tags "customer report, customer, customer name .... " is necessary. But in our case, tags shouldn't be given manually.

As there are nested tags in xml, we might have to create multiple tables in db and have dependencies too. We have no clue how to handle nested structure and to design database dynamically.

Comment: You could parse XML using JAVA as in http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Comment: we tried, java can't handle files that are of size in GBs

Comment: Normal machine will not be able to handle files of order GB. In normal scenarios you would load the whole XML file and parse it. But in this you have to iteratively parse the XML. In python something like `iterparse`. A quick google search shows `http://woodstox.codehaus.org/` could be used for JAVA

Comment: Hi Nikitha...we are also looking for simillar kind of solution...we want to process xml data dynamically with out giving start and end tag...please help us on this...thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle table adapter is very good at splitting large XML files:
http://docs.oracle.com/bigdata/bda49/BDCUG/oxh_hive.htm#BDCUG694

Other similar solutions use string matching or regular expressions to pull out the split XML elements.  This technique is error prone and can lead to unintentionally skipping data in the document.  Oracle's solution uses a combination of scanning and streaming parsers to identify split elements.  As a result, it is fast and handles a much larger class of use cases.

Download is here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/bdc/big-data-connectors/downloads/index.html

(Part of XQuery for Hadoop)